# uninitialized constant YARD::Handlers (NameError) - OSX 10.7.2, XCode 4.2, Ruby 1.9.2 using RVM,

Tags: rvm, osx-lion, ruby-1.9.2, xcode4.2

I'm getting the following error whenever trying to start a rails server.

`` /Users/craigspaeth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/yard-dm-0.1.1/lib/yard-dm/property_handler.rb:5:in `<module:DM>': uninitialized constant YARD::Handlers (NameError) ``

I'm setting up a development environment that works flawlessly on my 10.6.8 snow leopard laptop, but is having troubles running on my new imac machine.

I'm using ruby 1.9.2-p290 on OSX Lion 10.7.2 in 64bit on a brand new iMac with Xcode 4.2. I've cleared out my gemset and re-installed ruby countless times. I've tried removing my OSX version of ruby and pointing everything to my rvm version. I've re-installed the yard gem from a bundle install and straight gem install. I've tried to install 1.9.3, and 1.9.2-head instead of just `rvm install 1.9.2` (I get make errors).

Nothing.

Is there a known bug with the latest version of Lion and ruby 1.9.2 or Yard? I seem to be running in circles and can't find anything online to help.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, [a related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959723/rvm-error-when-installing-gems) was suggested installing 1.9.3 [based on this bug report/fix](http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/4651).  This worked for me and now yard works just fine in my Lion environment so give it another shot.  I'm on rvm 1.10.0-pre.